# NO ME APARECE LA CARPETA DE LIBRERIAS

Tags: netbeans, librería

AL MOMENTO DE CREAR MI PROYECTO WEB EN NETBEANS CON MAVEN - WEB APPLICATION NO ME CREA LA CARPETA DE LIBRERIAS YA QUE QUIERO AGREGAR UNA PARA CONECTAR CON BASE DE DATOS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]